# Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Container'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In the browser, I get the error

> Failed to compile Module not found: Can't resolve
>   '@material-ui/core/Container'

It's looking for the component inside of my components directory instead of node_modules. I can't change directories into node_modules `../../` because node_modules is outside of `src` directory and Create React App won't let me.

I've use yarn to remove and `$ yarn add @material-ui/core`. I've tried yarn run build which gives me the error

> Cannot find module: '@material-ui/core/Container'. Make sure this
>   package is installed. You can install this package by running: yarn
>   add @material-ui/core/Container.

When I try to add it, I get the error

> error Couldn't find package "@material-ui/core/Container" on the "npm"
>   registry.

Here's the dependencies I have that are related:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
```

I expect to see the contents of the page not take up the full width of the screen, but instead, I receive a fail to compile error.

Comment: It looks like `Container` is part of material-ui's "next" release, as I'm not able to find any references to it other than their [documentation](https://next.material-ui.com/api/container/) for the upcoming version.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Container` is not part of the `material-ui` version specified in your `package.json`.

To upgrade, run the following:

```
$ yarn add @material-ui/core@next
```

You might have to remove the old stable version (if that's even an option for you).

React and react-dom >= 16.8.0 are all that are needed as peer dependencies, so the experimental upgrade of `material-ui` should be all you need to use `Container`.

Comment: In my case I had to run npm `install @material-ui/core`, that is after initially installing with `@material-ui/core@next`

Comment: I needed `yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` now that it's renamed to MUI

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue and I resolved it by calling:

for npm:

`npm install @material-ui/core`

for yarn:

`$ yarn add @material-ui/core@next`

Answer (score 2):

you haven't installed **Material-UI** for the correct path.

step 1:
If windows-PC selects the correct path using terminal -> cd .\foldername

step2:
install **Material-UI**

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

Comment: Looks like the exact same answer was already given in 2021

Answer (score 1):

If you follow a `npx create-react-app new-app` with `cd new-app` and `yarn add @material-ui/core` it wile compile with `yarn start`. You might try just starting over.

However, to help your troubleshooting, this error typically happens when you try to use a Material-UI component and forget to import it. Have you tried commenting out all the code and seeing if it compiles?

This error might also indicate that there are no node_modules for what is being imported. So, `npm install` might solve the problem.

Comment: This app was created with `npx create-react-app new-app`. I did try to import the component: that's why I received the error. And yes, code works without Container.

Answer (score 1):

### Just install these below packages

- @emotion/react
- @emotion/styled
- @material-ui/core
- @material-ui/icons

Answer (score 1):

**Just Install:** npm install @material-ui/core

Answer (score 1):

For those trying to upgrade to Material Ui v5 (MUI v5)

See [this section](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/#replace-all-imports) of the migration doc to v5.

Some imports have changed name (not just the prefix)

```
@material-ui/core -> @mui/material
@material-ui/unstyled -> @mui/base
@material-ui/icons -> @mui/icons-material
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the same material UI package you have installed, latest MUI package is written as **@mui/package-name** and I installed **material-ui-dropzone** package and this package does not adapt to new material UI name conversion means it uses the old naming conversion of MUI, for example, **@material-ui/package-name**

The solution for this problem will be to install core material UI and other MUI packages using the old naming conversion for example **@material-ui/core** or **@material-ui/icons** instead of **@mui/core** or **@mui/icons**